# Autocompletion with Emacs and tags

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, emacs24, cedet

Hi I work on a very large and complex C code base (complex not in a good way). The codebase dwarfs the linux kernel to give you an idea. I have set up emacs to do most of what I want. I get autocompletion on functions and variables but there are certain things which do not work (omni-completion).

I use cedet v2, xgtags, auto-complete, yastnippet, cscope and a few other tools all of which are installed via el-get on emacs-24. When I work on a smaller project, omni-completion in C works so I would get a list of the members of a struct when I access the object. However, in the very large "project", omni-completion does not work when accessing a struct. As I said, I get completion on functions and variables but not on structures.

My explanation is that auto-completion is using its parser which cannot handle the size and complexity of the codebase. However, gtags or etags can handle it.

Is there a way to make auto-complete look into the gtags (xgtags) database? My gtags are working very well indeed.

EDIT:
I am not an admin on my system and I cannot install packages easily. At the moment, I do not have clang. Having said that, I am quite capable of compiling from source and can get many packages this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `ac-source-gtags` that is comes together with `auto-complete` package? You can also combine several sources, like described in [documentation](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Completion_with_specific_source)...

Answer (score 3):

Using clang+automplete is also an option:

http://truongtx.me/2013/03/06/emacs-ccpp-autocomplete-with-clang/

Edit: I see you've edited the question indicating you have no clang. I leave this answer here regardless, in case someone else finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that cedet is really underwhelming.
I would recommend using just one tool which does everything
https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags
It underlines errors as you type as well as using smart completions. Just add this to your init file after obtaining the required emacs packages

```
(require 'rtags)
(require 'popup)
(require 'rtags-ac)
(setq rtags-completions-enabled t)
(rtags-enable-standard-keybindings c-mode-base-map)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq ac-sources '(ac-source-rtags)
)))
```