# setting up emacs autcomplete with gtags

Tags: c++, emacs, elisp, gnu-global

I've been struggling with getting tags to work with auto-complete mode for quite a while now, and it seems like my attempts have been futile.

I have two questions:

1. How can I tell if auto-complete mode is working with gtags?
2. How do I setup gtags to work with auto-complete? (including the steps I need to do outside of emacs to get everything setup.)

Here's my situation:

I have a relatively large code base and I would like to index it with gtags, then use the gtags in my autocomplete for code hints. There are many levels of directories in the source, but they all belong to a root directory where I generated my gtags.

To my understanding, if I have everything correctly setup, I should be able to type a few letters, and get auto-complete based on gtags if the source is within the directories that gtags indexed. For example, if I have saved my gtags (by calling `gtags` from the command line) at the root directory like so:

```
Root_Project_Dir
├── GPATH
├── GRTAGS
├── GSYMS
├── GTAGS
│
├── Folder1
│   └──my_structs.h
├── Folder2
    └──some_code.cpp
```

Where my_structs.h has something defined like...

```
struct testStruct{
    int a;
    char blah_blah;
    double context;
};
```

Then that would mean that if I were to define this struct in some_code.cpp, auto-complete could attempt to complete my struct in the .cpp source. Is this correct? In other words, if I defined `testStruct mystruct = new testStruct();` then the next time I call something like "`mystruct->`", the autocomplete dialog should pop up with the members of the struct?

My toy .emacs file has the following bare bone auto-complete setup (along with the correct load path). It seems to be able to recognize and auto-complete code from within the working directory. However, it doesn't seem to be aware of anything beyond the directory that the source is currently in.

```
;; auto-complete stuff
require 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(defun ac-common-setup ()
  (setq ac-sources (append ac-sources '(ac-source-gtags))))
```

I've looked around a lot on the internet, but I haven't really found any solutions.
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708360/autocompletion-with-emacs-and-tags) post, but the solution just says to add ac-source-gtags. I think I need a little more instruction to get things working since I'm not too familiar with elisp.

Comment: auto-complete enables gtags completion in C, C++ as default. So you don't need special configuration for gtags, you just setup auto-complete.

Comment: @syohex does my auto-complete configuration look right above? Because the above configuration doesn't seem to be giving me code completion beyond the current working directory. Do I need to enable gtag-mode or require any other packages?

Comment: Left parenthesis is missed at 2nd line. And you need not to define `ac-common-setup`. You need not to enable gtags-mode or any other mode.

Comment: @syohex, does gtag-mode auto enable with ac-config-default?

Comment: No it does not. You can use gtags completion with following url configuration. https://gist.github.com/syohex/11164127

Comment: @syohex, Thanks for your help. I just tried the configuration given in your URL, however, I was not able to pick up the data from my header, which is in a different folder in a subdirectory. Please see http://pastebin.com/hg6a3HBn. I have ran gtags, when are in my root directory "/test", and my other files are in "/test/src/" and "/test/include". The modes I see enabled are (C++/l AC Abbrev). However, if I type "myClass.", no code hints show up.

Comment: Ah, sorry auto-complete with gtags cannot complete member name. It can complete function names, class names, method names, macros etc. You should use irony-mode or clang-complete-async which are based on clang for such purpose. https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode https://github.com/Golevka/emacs-clang-complete-async